# Prove $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}$ diverges and $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that this is a very simple question, but I'm struggling to find a convincing way tho show this. I'm trying to show that $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}$ diverges. I tried using the Ratio Test and the Root Test, but both of these are inconclusive. I know that $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, but I don't know how to show it for $n+1$.

Additionally, I would like to show that $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ converges, but again, using the Ratio Test and the Root Test gives an inconclusive result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the Integral Test on both.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} - 1$

Comment: It is strictly decreasing, so the sum converges iff the integral.

Comment: You can use the limit comparison test, and it is possibly the best test to apply here.

Comment: harmonic series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n+1}$$ diverges since $$\frac{1}{n+1}\geq \frac{1}{2n}$$ for all $n$ with $$n\geq 1$$
the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$ converges since we have $$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\le \frac{1}{n^2}$$ for all $n$ with $$n\geq 1$$

Answer (score 5):

Just open the summation to figure out:

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = 1+\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = 1+\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

- To preface, the [p-series](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) test states that given

  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^p}
  $$

  if $p > 1$, then the series converges. This can be proven with the [integral test](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Integral_test_for_convergence), which can be proven geometrically, but that is beyond the scope of this answer.
- Also, we will use the observation that given the notation

  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
  $$

  if two series have the same end behavior (that being, if two series' $a_n$ reach the same value as $n \rightarrow \infty$), then they either both converge or both diverge since it is the infinitieth terms that matter. This logic leads to the [limit comparison test](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Limit_comparison_test), but we will simply use this logic as justification.

### Divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n+1}$

Let's take a look at $\frac1{n+1}$. As $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac1{n+1} \rightarrow \frac1n$. This means that the series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \tag1 \label1
$$

has the same end behavior as our original series. By the p-series test, we see that $\eqref1$ diverges. Because this series has the same end behavior as the original, one can confidently assert that the original series diverges.

### Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\left ( n+1 \right )^2}$

Let's take a look at $\frac1{\left ( n+1 \right )^2}$. As $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac1{\left ( n+1 \right )^2} \rightarrow \frac1{n^2}$. This means that the series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2} \tag2 \label2
$$

has the same end behavior as our original series. By the p-series test, we see that $\eqref2$ converges. Because this series has the same end behavior as the original, one can confidently assert that the original series converges.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1/(n+1)$ and $1/(n+1)^2$ are decreasing and positive. Hence, by [Cauchy Condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), $∑ 2^n \frac{1}{2^{n}+1} ≥ ∑ 1/2 = \infty$ so $∑1/(n+1)$ diverges, and $∑ 2^n \frac{1}{(2^n+1)^2} ≤ ∑ \frac{1}{2^n} < ∞ $ so $∑1/(n+1)^2$ converges.